# DNS Issue - My old name servers still show up in the eurid WHOIS search

Tags: nameservers

I have recently transferred a .eu domain to a new registrar. I issued the NS synchronisation for over 72h now. When I go to my domain, I can see that it is still some times pointing to the old site (hosted with the old registrar), and others to the new one. I also have troubles with my emails. I cannot connect anymore to the old mail server, and neither to the new one. When I do a WHOIS search at eurid, it shows me the list of name servers associated to my domain. It shows four name servers. The two new ones, and the two old ones. Is this normal, and usually an indication/symptom of a slower than usual propagation, or does it indicate that the new registrar did something wrong with the DNS configuration?

Comment: You would want to remove the old name servers entirely. Check DNS records for each record with mxtoolbox.com and see what pop ups and which name servers are polled.

Comment: Thanks, Yu. I will get the registrar first to sort the ns entries out, and then definitely get them to address the email issue as well. Nice tool! I did not know about it.

Comment: Hey Eduardo . Did you manage to fix this issue? I tried everything and can't get the DNS-es to be removed from the Whois list. If I check the https://enduser.eurid.eu I see all 4 DNSes where I only have 2 in my zone file at the registrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really does sound like the registrar made a mistake. A WHOIS lookup shouldn't have cached information.  I recently updated my WHOIS information on a .com, and it was instantaneous.

Now, that doesn't mean that DNS lookups are going to propagate instantaneously however.  Since you used the phrase "WHOIS search", I'm not entirely certain you mean the standard "WHOIS" lookup.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I will contact the registrar (they were off on the weekend) and push them to do something about this.